# Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'. React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

when I install react-native-video in my react native app, my app shows an error. and I get the following error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - file:/C:/React-Native-Projects/GymBuddyApp/node_modules/react-native/android/com/yqritc/android-scalablevideoview/1.0.4/android-scalablevideoview-1.0.
> 4.pom

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your android/build.gradle file try to edit as follows the clean and build your project

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        .... # Keep the rest
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

refer to this if this solution isn't enough:
https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2468

Comment: Happy to help ^^ please mark the answer as correct if it helped you